# "expo-local-authentication" Authentication unsuccessful "missing_usage_description"

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, localauthentication

Here's a copy of my `app.json` requesting permission and providing description

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nhCJ.png)

and when run I face this message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6SD0.jpg)

```
await authenticateAsync({
      disableDeviceFallback: true,
      promptMessage: 'Login with Biometrics',
      cancelLabel: 'Cancel'
}).catch(error => console.log('bioError:: ', error))
```

Expecting to authenticate the user biometric and asking for permission.